# Removing digits from a number but it only works when we choose first digit

Tags: java

```
Enter a number: 1234
Enter a digit you want to remove: 2
New Number: 34
```

IM REMOVING ONLY SECOND DIGIT BUT IT IS ALSO REMOVING FIRST ONE

Tried to change method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    @author Başar Ballıöz

    int x = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter a number ");
    x = input.nextInt();

    String number = Integer.toString(x);

    System.out.print("Enter a digit you want to remove: ");
    int a;
    a = input.nextInt();
    int new_number = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(a));

    System.out.print("New Number: " + new_number);
}
```

I WANT TO SEE LIKE:

```
Enter a number: 1234
Enter a digit you want to remove: 2
New Number: 134
```

Comment: I'm sorry but its not very clear to me what you are asking. Could you clarify please?

Comment: I will fix it sorry for that

Comment: You are removing everything before the digit you want to remove. You need to add the first part, and the last part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `substring(a)` is the string from the (a+1)th digit until the end.  
You need to break the string in 2 parts. 
The 1st part is the string from the start until the digit to be removed (excluded) 
and the 2nd part is string after the the digit to be removed . 
Then rejoin the 2 strings:

```
System.out.print("Enter a digit you want to remove: ");
int a;
a = input.nextInt();
String newString = number.substring(0, a - 1) + number.substring(a);
int new_number = Integer.parseInt(newString);
```

this way you remove the (a+1)th digit.

Comment: can you explain your code more detailed ? It is worked perfectly but, i want to be more experienced.

Comment: This part: `number.substring(0, a - 1)` is the string before the char to be removed and this `number.substring(a)` is the part after that char. So I join them and I have what was the string before without that char(digit)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `replace` but it replaces all occurrences

> Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar

**replaceFirst** will only replace the first occurence

> Replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

```
int new_number = Integer.parseInt(number.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(a), ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `StringBuilder` class which is mutable.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            int x = 0;
            System.out.print("Enter a number ");
            x = input.nextInt();
            String number = Integer.toString(x);            
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(number);
            System.out.print("Enter a digit you want to remove: ");
            int a;
            a = input.nextInt();
            sb.deleteCharAt(a-1);  

            System.out.print("New Number: " + sb);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to use a `StringBuilder` (a *mutable* collection of characters). Also, I would prefer to declare and initialize the variables when used. Like,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number ");
int x = input.nextInt();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(x));
System.out.print("Enter a digit you want to remove: ");
int a = input.nextInt();
int new_number = Integer.parseInt(sb.replace(a, a + 1, "").toString());
System.out.print("New Number: " + new_number);
```